# Migratus: java.lang.Character cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Named

Tags: sqlite, clojure, database-migration

### Edit 2

Yogthos pushed Migratus 0.8.14 yesterday, which looks to have addressed the change to the `jdbc` API. But it's not on Clojars yet. I will report back once I figure out how to build the new version and put it on my classpath.

### Edit

Perhaps this is related to the breaking changes in `clojure.java.jdbc` 0.6.0, which now, among other things, requires

```
(clojure.java.jdbc/create-table-ddl 
  :bar 
  [[:id :serial "primary key"] ; a vector rather than multiple arities
   [:name :text]])
```

rather than

```
(clojure.java.jdbc/create-table-ddl
  :bar
  [:id :serial "primary key"]
  [:name :text])
```

Just a thought.

---

I am trying to follow along with the example at https://github.com/yogthos/migratus, but use SQLite [edit: same problem with postgresql]. The pertinent files are like so:

```
├── project.clj
├── resources
│   └── migrations
│       ├── 20160419231827-foo.down.sql
│       └── 20160419231827-foo.up.sql
├── src
│   └── foo
│       ├── core.clj
│       └── my-migrations.clj
```

`project.clj` is like this:

```
(defproject foo "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [migratus "0.8.13"]
                 [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.6.0-alpha2"]
                 [org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc "3.8.11.2"]
                 [org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 "1.7.9"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot foo.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

And the `my-migrations.clj` is like this:

```
(ns foo.my-migrations
  (:require [migratus.core :as migratus]))

(def config {:store :database
            :migration-dir "migrations/"
            :migration-table-name "foo_bar"
            :db {:classname "org.sqlite.JDBC"
                  :subprotocol "sqlite"
                  :connection-uri "jdbc:sqlite:site.db"}})

(migratus/migrate config)
```

The migration files are verbatim from the documentation (with filenames updated to the current date/time). This leads to the following error:

```
  Show: Clojure Java REPL Tooling Duplicates All  (12 frames hidden)

1. Unhandled java.lang.ClassCastException
  java.lang.Character cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Named

                  core.clj: 1546  clojure.core/name
                  core.clj: 1540  clojure.core/name
                  jdbc.clj:   62  clojure.java.jdbc/as-sql-name
                  jdbc.clj:   51  clojure.java.jdbc/as-sql-name
                  jdbc.clj: 1090  clojure.java.jdbc/create-table-ddl/spec-to-string
                  core.clj: 2644  clojure.core/map/fn
              LazySeq.java:   40  clojure.lang.LazySeq/sval
              LazySeq.java:   49  clojure.lang.LazySeq/seq
              LazySeq.java:   71  clojure.lang.LazySeq/first
                  RT.java:  667  clojure.lang.RT/first
                  core.clj:   55  clojure.core/first
                string.clj:  180  clojure.string/join
                string.clj:  180  clojure.string/join
                  jdbc.clj: 1094  clojure.java.jdbc/create-table-ddl
                  jdbc.clj: 1079  clojure.java.jdbc/create-table-ddl
                  jdbc.clj: 1084  clojure.java.jdbc/create-table-ddl
                  jdbc.clj: 1079  clojure.java.jdbc/create-table-ddl
              database.clj:  227  migratus.database/init-schema!/fn
                  jdbc.clj:  591  clojure.java.jdbc/db-transaction*
                  jdbc.clj:  563  clojure.java.jdbc/db-transaction*
                  jdbc.clj:  576  clojure.java.jdbc/db-transaction*
                  jdbc.clj:  563  clojure.java.jdbc/db-transaction*
              database.clj:  220  migratus.database/init-schema!
              database.clj:  219  migratus.database/init-schema!
              database.clj:  262  migratus.database.Database/connect
                  core.clj:   24  migratus.core/run
                  core.clj:   21  migratus.core/run
                  core.clj:   63  migratus.core/migrate
                  core.clj:   60  migratus.core/migrate
                      REPL:   11  foo.my-migrations/eval21297
                      REPL:   11  foo.my-migrations/eval21297
            Compiler.java: 6927  clojure.lang.Compiler/eval
            Compiler.java: 6890  clojure.lang.Compiler/eval
                  core.clj: 3105  clojure.core/eval
                  core.clj: 3101  clojure.core/eval
                  main.clj:  240  clojure.main/repl/read-eval-print/fn
                  main.clj:  240  clojure.main/repl/read-eval-print
                  main.clj:  258  clojure.main/repl/fn
                  main.clj:  258  clojure.main/repl
                  main.clj:  174  clojure.main/repl
              RestFn.java: 1523  clojure.lang.RestFn/invoke
    interruptible_eval.clj:   87  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate/fn
                  AFn.java:  152  clojure.lang.AFn/applyToHelper
                  AFn.java:  144  clojure.lang.AFn/applyTo
                  core.clj:  646  clojure.core/apply
                  core.clj: 1881  clojure.core/with-bindings*
                  core.clj: 1881  clojure.core/with-bindings*
              RestFn.java:  425  clojure.lang.RestFn/invoke
    interruptible_eval.clj:   85  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate
    interruptible_eval.clj:   55  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate
    interruptible_eval.clj:  222  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/interruptible-eval/fn/fn
    interruptible_eval.clj:  190  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/run-next/fn
                  AFn.java:   22  clojure.lang.AFn/run
  ThreadPoolExecutor.java: 1142  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor/runWorker
  ThreadPoolExecutor.java:  617  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker/run
              Thread.java:  745  java.lang.Thread/run
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Final Edit (I hope):

Version 0.8.14 of Migratus is now on Clojars.

---

This was because of breaking changes in `clojure.java.jdbc` version 0.6.0. The API changed to require `create-table-ddl` to wrap the table specs in a single vector rather than as multiple arities. Yogthos fixed this yesterday with version 0.8.13 → 0.8.14, see [here](https://github.com/yogthos/migratus/commit/6355209ade2f17b1b833caf4da9e23736206353a). Clojars does not have Migratus version 0.8.14 (and the Migratus readme still has 0.8.13). So I did

```
$> git clone https://github.com/yogthos/migratus
$> cd migratus
$> lein install
```

Now it works.